# Check answer button has incorrect input string format

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a check answer button. I have not learned how to use methods yet so i cannot use them in this. I first need to check if the math operation is subtraction or addition and then go from there. Visual studio does not detect any errors but when i run the program and try to check the answer ive inputted i get an error telling me unhandled exception has occured and that input string was not in correct format. I have a feeling the proble is with my int lblMath but im not sure how else to check what the value is inside of that lbl.

```
 {
            int First = int.Parse(lblFirst.Text);//The first number in the math equation
            int Second = int.Parse(lblSecond.Text);//The second number in the math equation
            int UserAnswer = Convert.ToInt32(txtAnswer.Text);//The users answer to math question
            int lblMath = int.Parse(lblMathType.Text);//Whether the symbol is + or -
            if(lblMath == '+')
            {
                int AnswerAdd = First + Second;
                //Answer is addition
                if(UserAnswer == AnswerAdd)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Correct");
                }
                else if(UserAnswer != AnswerAdd)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Wrong Answer");
                }
            }
            else if (lblMath == '-')
            {
                int AnswerSub = First - Second; 
                //Answer is subtraction
                if(UserAnswer == AnswerSub)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Correct");
                }
                else if (UserAnswer != AnswerSub)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Wrong Answer");
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're expecting this to be an integer:

```
int lblMath = int.Parse(lblMathType.Text);
```

But then you're immediately expecting it to be a string:

```
if(lblMath == '+')
```

(I'm honestly surprised this even compiles.)

What *integer value* to you expect the string `"+"` to be and why?  The exception is telling you that the string `"+"` is not an integer.  Because it isn't.

It's a string.  Use it as a string:

```
string lblMath = lblMathType.Text;
```